# Edit button text in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

**Q>** I want to show a GridView button's text as hard coded and a event to fire on  button click. How to achieve this ?

Till now I've been able to come this far

[image: GridView Sample]

But I want to show button text as **Read** or **Delete** not the value in the Read/Delete column.
The code I've used

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="MID" DataSourceID="inbox" EnableModelValidation="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<Columns>
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" DataTextField="MID" HeaderText="Read" 
  Text="Read" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MID" HeaderText="MID" InsertVisible="False" 
  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="sender" HeaderText="sender" 
  SortExpression="sender" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="subject" HeaderText="subject" 
  SortExpression="subject" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="on" HeaderText="on" SortExpression="on" />
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" DataTextField="MID" HeaderText="Delete" 
  Text="Delete" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="inbox" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [MID], [sender], [subject], [on] FROM [mail]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the text to appear as "Delete" or "Read", then simply don't set the `DataTextField` property to use the `MID` property of the result and instead set the `CommandName` property as so:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName='<%#Eval("MMID")%>' HeaderText="Delete" 
  Text="Delete" />
```

As far as handling the `OnClick` event of the buttons, you can handle the `OnRowCommand` event on the GridView as so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

Now add the code behind:

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

  string MMID = e.CommandName;
  if( (e.CommandSource as ButtonField).Text=="Delete")
  {
             //oh, I should delete this MMID
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Above code does not work. ButtonField is as useful as nipples are to men. Instead use an ItemTemplateField as so:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MID") %>'
                    Text="Delete" />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then the GridView_RowCommand becomes this:

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string mid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
        // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Cause I need the MID for an event

Comment: @Sourav check my update. That will work and you will be able to retrieve the MID property easily.

Comment: **Error Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField does not have a DataBinding event.**

Comment: @Sourav provided a second update. I am baffled that `ButtonField` does not behave identically to a `<asp:Button>` and does not have a `DataBinding` event even though it should. What a useless column that is...

Comment: **Deleting is not supported by data source 'inbox' unless DeleteCommand is specified.** What in case I just need to show the MID on a Label ?

Comment: @Sourav no, you need to specify the `DeleteCommand` in your `SQLDataSource` adding a Parameter (such as the MID). You have work to do... I thought you were calling a `DAL` to delete the record and that's why you wanted to retrieve `MID ` on the `RowCommand` event.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Actually I was planning to do the delete myself. Not a prob bro, can fix that (:

Comment: But What if I want to show the MID to any other control ? i.e Showing MID on a Label !

Comment: @Sourav that's not a problem. You are already doing it on the MID column, aren't you?

Comment: That's why you have the `DataKeys` set to `MID`. You can always retrieve it from there. Or you can make the `MID` column `Visible=False`... I mean, there are many ways to go about this...